# Why does 1/(1 - ((n-1)/n)^n) approximate e/(e-1)?

Tags: algorithms

1/(1 - ((n-1)/n)^n) seems to approximate e/e-1. 1/(1 - ((10^150-1)/10^150)^10^150) gets the first 31 decimals of e/(e-1), with perfect precision. Why?

Comment: $[(n-1)/n]^n\to e^{-1}$. Also please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/

Comment: thanks. could you give me some keywords or links to where I can read about why ((n-1)/n)^n = 1/e?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $$f(n)=\frac{1}{\left(1-\left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right)^n\right)}$$
This is only an asymptotic result as $n\rightarrow \infty$, then$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^n=e^{-1}.$$ So $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f(n) =\frac{e}{e-1}$$
However, $f(1)=1, f(2)=1.3333, f(3)=1.4210,f(4)=1.4628,...f(\infty)=e/(e-1)=1.5819$

Answer (score 1):

You could get much more than the limit is you compose Taylor series.

Considering
$$f(n)=\frac{1}{\left(1-\left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right)^n\right)}$$ let
$$a_n=\left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right)^n\implies \log(a_n)=n\log\left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right)=n\log\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)$$ Now, use
$$\log\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)=-\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{2 n^2}-\frac{1}{3 n^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right)$$ which makes
$$\log(a_n)=-1-\frac{1}{2 n}-\frac{1}{3 n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$$ 
Continue with Taylor series using
$$a_n=e^{\log(a_n)}=\frac{1}{e}-\frac{1}{2 e n}-\frac{5}{24 e n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$$ All of the above makes
$$f(n)=\frac 1{\left(1-\frac{1}{e}\right)+\frac{1}{2 e n}+\frac{5}{24 e n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right) }$$ Now, long division to get
$$f(n)=\frac e {e-1} \left(1-\frac{1}{2 (e-1) n}+\frac{11-5 e}{24 (e-1)^2
   n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right) \right)$$

Try with $n=5$; the exact result is $\frac{3125}{2101}\sim 1.48739$ while the above truncated expression would give $\frac{e \left(671-1265 e+600 e^2\right)}{600 (e-1)^3}\sim 1.48760$.